# My Unity in settings

Tags: unity

Some time ago I installed My Unity, which is unofficial Unity configurator. Everything was normal until yesterday, when the system, after the update, chosen My Unity for one part of settings. Why?
[image: Here's a picture:]

Comment: you are referring to a 12.04 beta issue - but I dont understand your question "My Unity chosen one set of parts - why?" - can I kindly suggest you use Google Translate to help with your question?

Comment: I fixed it sentence.

Comment: are you asking why MyUnity is now part of System Settings - or are you asking why MyUnity has been removed from System Settings?

Comment: No. I am not asking it. I am asking Why is MyUnity one part of settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not "the system" that has chosen to place MyUnity in System Settings. It is the MyUnity developers. I had a chat with Gnome Design about something similar a while back, and I got the impression it's not supposed to be used that way. But it isn't impossible.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking why MyUnity has now appeared in the System Settings.

System Settings is the package `gnome-control-center`.  This is an integrated set of applets.  However, it has the ability to include *.desktop* files for other applications.

MyUnity is one such .desktop file that 12.04 `gnome-control-center` will recognise and will display its applet.

However - it isnt integrated as other applets in `gnome-control-center` - it just will just launch an external window.

As an aside - the always [excellent 2buntu](http://www.2buntu.com/1112/should-ubuntu-switch-to-switchboard/) has a fascinating blog entry for a proposal for replacing `gnome-control-center` to produce a more integrated solution  if you want to understand this further.